# Expo EAS build not exposing secrets when being accessed with `process.env.X`

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have tried to create secrets for my Expo app using both the EAS CLI and the Expo website, according to the documentation:`https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/`. However, after I have made an EAS build for Android with the command: `eas build -p android --profile <profile_name>`, and run it through the installation link on my physical Android device.

It seems that when I try to view the secrets through `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME` (Through alerts), it just gives me `undefined`.

I was wondering if anyone have faced this issue before and perhaps found a solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. I looked at the logs in the expo website and I could see under the "spin up build environment" section that the secrets were being exposed during the build. Problem is, that expo does not automatically inject the secret values under the process.env variables. In order to catch these values you can use a tool such as the babel plugin [transform-inline-environment-variables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables).

Comment: find this answer conflicting with expo docs https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/#accessing-secrets-in-eas-build "After creating a secret, you can read it on subsequent EAS Build jobs with `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME` from Node.js or in shell scripts as `$VARIABLE_NAME`."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as Jhonnatan says, you can use the `transform-inline-environment-variables` plugin. I'll show you.

First, install the dependency.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables
```

Then, add the plugin to your `babel.config.js` file. It would look something like this:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['transform-inline-environment-variables'],
  };
};
```

After that I recommend creating a `.env` file in your project, for example, to a API URL base, in this case, for a server running locally in your machine:

```
API_URL_BASE = http://10.0.2.2:3001
```

Remember that the `.env` file shouldn't be pushed to GitHub, because that is usually where we store sensitive data.

At this point, you can use environment variables directly in your source code, with `process.env.API_URL_BASE`. Literally anywhere in your code. When you modify `babel.config.js`, you should always restart the development server and clear the cache, so start your project with `npx expo start --clear`.

Okey, but what happened if I want to use another `API_URL_BASE` in production `(EAS Build)`? No problem, you need to add a `secret` to your EAS project.

Go to your project (https://expo.dev/accounts/my-username/projects/my-project) and in the Dashboard choose `Secrets`.

[image]

Then `Create`.

[image]

Finally, set the name of the secret (same as the `.env` file) and the value that you want for production environment.

[image]

And that's it! When you develop on your local machine, it will use the `API_URL_BASE` from your `.env` file, and when you build your app, EAS will take the `API_URL_BASE` from the secrets.

I hope that works for you! Any questions are available. Regards :)

Comment: Nice explanation. But how do you use with three or more environments? (i.e.: development, preview and production)

Comment: I would like to know the answer for that question

Comment: Sorry for the delay @DannyP. Certainly, this approach may not be the best for handling two possible values for a single variable. A solution could be to have an environment variable with the environment of the application, and then two or more variables per environment with the respective values. For example, you could have ENVIRONMENT, API_URL_BASE_PROD, and API_URL_BASE_TEST. So, in the code, you can make a logic based on ENVIRONMENT, to choose the production or test url.